# User Defined Function in Personal.xlsb file is hanging up Excel. Is there a way to avoid this, and optimize execution?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, user-defined-functions

I've created a user defined function in VBA, and saved it in Personal.xlsb file in order to have it available for all books. The intention of this function is to receive a range and a number. For all the numbers in the range, the first step is to round it to the next multiple of the specified number received as argument. After doing that rounding, the next step is to calculate the mode. The function is as follows:

```
Function ROUNDEDMODEV(rng As Variant, multiple As Variant)
    ' Array with the values from the selected range.
    Dim cellRange() As Variant
    ' Copy the specified range values to array
    cellRange = rng
    ' Looping through the array.
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(cellRange, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
        For c = 1 To UBound(cellRange, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.
            On Error Resume Next
            cellRange(r, c) = WorksheetFunction.MRound(cellRange(r, c), multiple)
        Next c
    Next r
    ROUNDEDMODEV = WorksheetFunction.mode(cellRange)
End Function
```

The way I'm calling this the following:

```
=PERSONAL.XLSB!ROUNDEDMODEV(IF($B$2:$B$20="some text", $C$2:$Z$20),0.5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider changing the signature to make the expected data types more explicit:

```
Public Function ROUNDEDMODEV(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal multiple As Double) As Variant
```

A `Variant` can very well wrap a 2D variant array; consider declaring `cellRange` as follows:

```
Dim cellRange As Variant
```

The `rng` parameter being a `Range` (yours is a `Variant/Range` at run-time), it's an object, and objects don't quite work like values - this assignment involves a process named *let coercion*:

> ```
> cellRange = rng
> ```

Let-coerced objects need to have a *default member* (if they don't, error 438 is raised) - in the case of the `Excel.Range` class, the default member is a hidden property named `[_Default]`, that essentially invokes the `Item` property when parameterized... or the `Value` property otherwise. So we can make that assignment much more explicit about what's going on, like this:

```
cellRange = rng.Value
```

One note about this:

> ```
>     For c = 1 To UBound(cellRange, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.
>         On Error Resume Next
> ```

Because error handling is never restored (`On Error GoTo 0`), only the first iteration sees the `On Error` statement have any effect. Consider restoring error handling after the "dangerous" statement:

```
On Error Resume Next
cellRange(r, c) = WorksheetFunction.MRound(cellRange(r, c), multiple)
On Error GoTo 0
```

If an error is raised, it will be while evaluating the right-hand side of the assignment; in such cases, `cellRange(r, c)` will remain `Variant/Empty`.

When needed, you can make a `Variant`-returning function yield a worksheet error using the `CVErr` function:

```
ROUNDEDMODEV = CVErr(xlErrValue) 'xlErrNA, etc.
```

If your function does not need to *return* error codes, consider declaring its return type explicitly:

```
Public Function ROUNDEDMODEV(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal multiple As Double) As Double
```

When testing your UDF, invoke it from the VBE's *immediate* toolwindow (Ctrl+G), not from a worksheet cell: a `#VALUE!` error likely means your function is throwing an unhandled error, and invoking it from VBA code (or the *immediate* pane) would give you much more debugging information.

Comment: I've added the corrections you indicated before, however I'm new to the immediate window usage. Since I have this UDF in Personal.xlsb file, how should I invoke it?
I've tried: PERSONAL.XLSB!ROUNDEDMODEV(IF($B$2:$B$20="test", $C$2:$Z$20),0.05), but it's giving me error saying "Expected: expression"

Comment: Have the module with the UDF active in the VBE, then ctrl+g and `?roundedmodev([IF($B$2:$B$20="test", $C$2:$Z$20)],0.05)`; the `?` is shorthand for `Print`

Comment: Sorry for asking again. Trying in the Immediate window, I'm having "Object required" error if I try with `? roundedmodev([IF($M$2:$M10="test",$N$2:$Q10)],0.05)`  . I've also added some breakpoints at the start of the function, and in the line `cellRange = rng.Value`, but I'm still getting the #VALUE! error (and it seems to not be entering to the function).

Comment: Running the same in immediate window, but using `Variant` instead of `Range` for `rng` in the definition of the function, works fine. However, if I try to run that in the Excel sheet, it will hang up.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
Function ROUNDEDMODEV(rng As Variant, multiple As Variant)
```

with:

```
Function ROUNDEDMODEV(rng As Range, multiple As Variant)
```

On my system *(Win 10 / Excel 365)* VBA was unable to resolve the Range `rng` into the 2-D array `cellRange` unless I explicitly Dim'ed as a Range.

Comment: This was the way I had the function before, and if I do it in that way, it gaves me #VALUE! error.

Comment: @Helbirah `#VALUE!` likely means your function is throwing an unhandled error. Try invoking it from the debug/immediate pane (Ctrl+G)